# Bash variable ${DIRSTACK[@]} for zsh

Tags: zsh, environment-variables

What the Zsh equivalent of Bash's `${DIRSTACK[@]}` variable?

Comment: That depends on what you want to use it for.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! If you need help merging accounts, please use the [Contact](https://unix.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of any page.  Also note that if you create new accounts to circumvent being temporarily blocked from asking questions, you risk being suspended.  See also the Help centre page called [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing relevant appears in the [list of parameters set by zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Set-By-The-Shell), but the [parameter module](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fparameter-Module) has a [`dirstack`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-dirstack) array which is similar to bash's `DIRSTACK`.

The easiest way to find this is to look for `dir_stack` or `dirstack` or `dirs` in  the [index of variables in the manual](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Variables-Index.html).

Note that in zsh, the current directory is not in the `dirstack` array, whereas in bash it is. But zsh array indexes start at 1 whereas bash array indexes start at 0. So for the directory that was current just before the last `pushd` command, the index is 1 in both shells.